# Problema ao popular DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estou fazendo a população de um [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), mas não sei por qual motivo não está mostrando.

Result:

[image: Resultado]

Só é retornado as linhas vazias.

<sub>**Fiscalizacao.cs**</sub>

```
public class Fiscalizacoes
    {
        private String Concessionaria { get; set; }
        private String Municipio { get; set; }
        private String Sistemas { get; set; }
        private DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
        private DateTime DataFim { get; set; }
        private String Status { get; set; }

        public Fiscalizacoes()
        {

        }

        public Fiscalizacoes(String concessionaria, String municipio, String sistemas, DateTime datainicio,
            DateTime datafim, String status)
        {
            Concessionaria = concessionaria;
            Municipio = municipio;
            Sistemas = sistemas;
            DataInicio = datainicio;
            DataFim = datafim;
            Status = status;
        }
    }
```

<sub>**populaGrid()**</sub>

```
private static IEnumerable<Fiscalizacoes> popularGrid()
        {
            var listaFiscalizacao = new List<Fiscalizacoes>
            {
                new Fiscalizacoes("SABESP", "São Paulo", "Abastecimento Água", new DateTime(2014, 12, 1),
                    new DateTime(2014, 12, 10), "Não Respondido"),
                new Fiscalizacoes("Mairinque", "Taubaté", "Esgotamento Sanitário", new DateTime(2014, 12, 1),
                    new DateTime(2014, 12, 10), "Respondido"),
                new Fiscalizacoes("Foz Gertrudes", "São José dos Campos", "Esgotamento Sanitário", new DateTime(2014, 12, 1),
                    new DateTime(2014, 12, 10), "Transmitido")
            };

            return listaFiscalizacao;
        }
```

<sub>**XAML**</sub>

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridFiscalizacoes" ItemsSource="{Binding listaFiscalizacao}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Concessionária" Binding="{Binding Concessionaria}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Município" Binding="{Binding Municipio}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sistemas" Binding="{Binding Sistemas}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data Início" Binding="{Binding DataInicio}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data Fim" Binding="{Binding DataFim}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status Checklist" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

<sub>**window**</sub>

```
 public ChecklistListagem(InicioWindow w)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.w = w;
            dataGridFiscalizacoes.ItemsSource = popularGrid();
        }
```

Comment: Em algum evento você está associando o ItemSource? `dataGridFiscalizacoes.ItemsSource = popularGrid();`

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Sim, estou associando. Esqueci de colocar...

Comment: Já tentou alterar o escopo de suas propriedades para público?

Comment: @JônatasHudler era exatamente isso!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não costumo trabalhar com o `Binding` desta forma. Vou colocar abaixo a forma como o utilizo.

### Primeiro:

No `DataGrid` apenas aponte o ItemsSource para `Binding`. E adicione no `Binding` o `Path`:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridFiscalizacoes" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Concessionária" Binding="{Binding Path=Concessionaria, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Município" Binding="{Binding Path=Municipio, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sistemas" Binding="{Binding Path=Sistemas, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data Início" Binding="{Binding Path=DataInicio, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data Fim" Binding="{Binding Path=DataFim, Mode=OneWay }" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status Checklist" Binding="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
```

### Segundo:

Você precisa em algum evento associar o `ItemsSource`. Vou supor que seja no construtor da `Window`:

```
public MinhaWindow(){
    dataGridFiscalizacoes.ItemsSource = popularGrid();
}
```

### Terceiro:

Como o @JônatasHudler colocou nos comentários as propriedades da classe precisam estar públicas:

```
public class Fiscalizacoes
    {
        public String Concessionaria { get; set; }
        public String Municipio { get; set; }
        public String Sistemas { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataFim { get; set; }
        public String Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: O `Path` não da certo, dá erro: `Type 'Path' is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension.`

Comment: Esqueci do = depois do Path. Tenta agora fazendo favor!

Comment: Não deu erro, mas também não mostrou nada, continua do mesmo jeito

Comment: Adicione o `Mode` no `Binding`. Por exemplo `Mode=OneWay`

Comment: Ainda continua do mesmo jeito, rs

Comment: Acabei de ver o comentário do @JônatasHudler, tava testando aqui, tinha chegado nisso... rsrsrs